# A question about applying strong law of large numbers

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

Let $p, q$ be two strictly-positive probability mass functions on a finite space $\Omega$. Let $X_1, X_2 \cdots, \overset{i.d.d}{\sim} q$ and $Y \sim p $. Let $f: \Omega \to \mathbb R$. Define $\omega(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$. Show that $\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nf(X_i)\omega(X_i)}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\omega(X_i)} \to E[f(Y)]$ almost surely.

For the definition of probability mass function, [see](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Probability_mass_function#/Formal_definition)

---

This is a Comprehensive exam practice problem given by our instructor but to be honest, it looks quite terrifying to me, what's the idea of how to approach and solve this problem?

Comment: A hint to get you off the ground: divide top and bottom by $n$. Now do you see anything familiar-looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my hint a little bit: after you divide top and bottom by $n$, the top is the sample mean of $f(X) \omega(X)$ and the bottom is the sample mean of just $\omega(X)$. By SLLN both those sample means converge. What do they converge to?

Comment: $E[f(X_1) \cdot \frac{p(X_1)}{q(X_1)}]$ and $E[\frac{p(X_1)}{q(X_1)}]$. How to decouple these things. Actually I really have trouble understanding what does $ \frac{p(X_1)}{q(X_1)}$ mean?

Comment: @Beginner Write down what $E[f(X_1) p(X_1)]/q(X_1)]$ actually is, given what you are told about the distribution of $X_i$.

Comment: @lan  Thank you I got it!

Comment: Sorry, one more question, I end up writing something like $\sum\limits_{\omega_i \in \Omega} f(\omega_i) p_{X_1}(\omega_i) = E[f(Y)]$. Is this correct? $X_1 \sim q$, not $p$, but it seems correct to me.

Comment: @Beginner With $p_{X_i}$ i.e. the PMF of $X_i$ that is not correct because as you say $X_i \sim q$, not $p$. That is correct with $p$ instead of $p_{X_i}$, though.